# Buildozer error ./gradlew failed

Tags: python, kivy, cython, gradlew, buildozer

I have problem when compiling my first kivy example and i get this. Yesterday it was everything ok, but today buildozer inn't worknig. I tried reinstall cython, upgrading and nothing helped. I have cython==0.21. 
Ubuntu  14.04.01 LTS

Any ideas ?
I dont know what to do

Some logs from buildozer  :

```
 [INFO]:    Selecting java build tool:
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 27.0.1
[INFO]:        Building with gradle, as gradle executable is present
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: EC parameters error
[DEBUG]:        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
(*) A LOT OF JAVA LOGS
[DEBUG]:        at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:199)
    [DEBUG]:        at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.getAlgorithmParameters(ECParameters.java:279)
    [DEBUG]:        ... 30 more
    Exception in thread background thread for pid 2003:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
      File "/home/sebastian/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2170, in background_thread
        handle_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/home/sebastian/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1929, in fn
        return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/home/sebastian/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
        raise exc
    ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: ./gradlew assembleDebug

  STDOUT:
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: EC parameters error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1872)

  STDERR:


[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 51):
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1459)  
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)  
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:697)    
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:199)  
    at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.getAlgorithmParameters(ECParameters.java:279)   
    ... 30 more
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/sebastian/Pulpit/vibr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp && ./gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: ./gradlew failed!
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --android_api 19 --sdk 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/sebastian/Pulpit/vibr/.buildozer/android/app --permission VIBRATE --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir=/home/sebastian/Pulpit/vibr/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: `# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2` ← as the error says, please post the full log.

Comment: I added better logs

Comment: Hmm, looks like some kind of downloading issue within gradle. I haven't seen this before, will try to reproduce.

Comment: Solved. I reinstalled all.

Comment: @Sebaklakier Hi, sorry for interrupt. I am currently having similar issue with building `.apk`. May i know how you **reinstalled all** ? Thanks.

Comment: I have Ubuntu on portable drive, so i reinstalled Ubuntu and again reinstalled buildozer, kivy etc

Comment: It did not work for me. I also use Linux in VirtualBox.. just upgraded the VM.